# NGINX in between load balance and Apache?

Tags: apache, load-balancing, nginx

I have recently joined the company where I see below stack to handle the http request

> CDN ->  LVS(Load balancer) -> NGINX -> Apache

My question is about using advantage of NGINX b/w Load balancer and Apache. Folks who took this decision left and most of the team is new.
I read couple of articles on google where most says NGINX and apache are used together where NGINX can work for caching static content(but 
we are using CDN here). Another reason is where NGINX can be used as Load balancer(but I see LVS is used for this).

So what are the other good reason to use Nginx in front of apache in general apart from caching and load balacing(reverse proxy) ?

Comment: Have you checked what they're configured to do? It might be just be that the devs preferred working with Nginx but had a load of legacy Apache modules that they didn't want to port so ran a passthough for those bits.